# Prevent extra warning options when using CMake's Xcode generator

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

When using the Xcode generator with a CMake project, a large number of compiler warnings will be enabled. How can I prevent this, and have the same warnings as with other generators?

**Short example:**

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(example)

add_executable(ex ex.c)
```

```c
// ex.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    long l = 1;
    int i = l;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Build using:

```bash
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -GXcode
VERBOSE=1 cmake --build .
```

I see the following warning options on the compiler command line, none of which are present with other generators:

```
-Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-implicit-fallthrough
```

Of course this triggers the following warning:

```
ex.c:6:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer
      precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    int i = l;
        ~   ^
1 warning generated.
```

**Question:** Is there a way to prevent using all these warning, without leaving the command line?

Motivation: I am looking to use Xcode's excellent static analysis feature on my project without having to sort through a large number of irrelevant warnings.